# Row number function in wrangler in Cloud data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, google-cloud-storage

I have data in GCS bucket and i want to create a new column row_number() and find a max of record from the original data. For example,below is my raw data.

```
ID  MEMBER_ID   SERVICE
3   234     xyz
4   234     abc
1   123     hyts
4   876     bts
10  876     xyz
```

and i want the output as below to my bigquery table.

```
ID     MEMBER_ID      SERVICE
4       234             abc
1       123             hyts
10      876             xyz
```

can you please suggest the possible way to do this in cloud data fusion.

Comment: May I know what attempted steps you have taken? I believe its a good starting point for the community to answer your question. Also I did not get the expected output, are the spaces are\ delimiters ?

Comment: Hi , have tried to do via wrangler , but its having plugin for group by.. but not sure how do to with that. i just gave sample data here in my file.. yeah spaces can be considered as delimiters

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Deduplicate plugin (you can find it under the Analytics section in Pipeline Studio) to get the row with the max id for each member_id.

[image]